# CSS not linking with HTML

Tags: html, css

My styles are not showing up. I linked it like normal, it made sure the name was correct, the are in the same directory, but still nothing. It works on every other web page I make, it just isn't working right now.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="classyclass.css">
    <title>Classy Fun</title>
</head>
```

CSS:

```
body 
{ 
   color: white; 
   background-color: navy; 
   font-family: Times; 
}
```

That is just a sample of the code, there is more.

Edit: It works in IE, but not Chrome.

I tried it on a different computer, it still only works in IE.

Comment: What is `<<!DOCTYPE html>`? You need to either correct your syntax, or learn to post *actual code*.

Comment: Check path to the file. Is your css in the same folder as this html file ?

Comment: Is the CSS you have posted beneath your `<head>` element actually not inside `<style>` tags or is that just a typo in this post?

Comment: Validate your [HTML](http://validator.w3.org/). Validate your [CSS](http://validator.w3.org/). Check your browser's developer tools' Net tab to make sure the right CSS is being requested and that the data is coming back in the response.

Comment: Judging by what you've posted you need to add <style> tags around your CSS. Unless of course you've not separated out the code for us

Comment: @DrydenLong — Presumably it is in classyclass.css

Comment: Presumably...I would edit but you never know.

Comment: @ian It is in different files, the code won't separate though...

Comment: What version of IE is this?

Comment: We need a lot more information--demo page, rest of the code, screenshot, etc.

Comment: follow @Quentin 's advice to see if it is a problem with the file loading or with the CSS as such. if it is a CSS problem (style information is there but doesn't get used in chrome), start a new question about the CSS code

Comment: @Ian Internet Explorer 11

Comment: Close your html tag - '</html>'

Comment: You can watch the web console to see if the css gets loaded.

Comment: @Scott — the end tag for the html element is optional.

Comment: I've copy and pasted your code, put the html file and css class in the same directory, and tested it in chrome, and everything works just fine. Is there something you may have forgot to mention?

Comment: @Quentin So if it's optional, why does anyone ever bother to put it in? Is this an optional thing depending on your servers settings just like the `<?php ?>` ?

Comment: Because most people don't know it is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clear your browser cache.  You can do that by pressing `ctrl` + `alt` + `delete` and select `cache`.  If you are using an older version of Internet Explorer you will need to go to `tools->Internet Options`.

`ctrl` + `F5` also reloads everything without cache in most browsers.

Comment: and what about other (better? ;) ) browser? - in most browser ctrl + f5 reloads everything without using cache

Comment: Or just load your site in private browsing